# "Try Ubuntu" freezes on Surface laptop 4 AMD

Tags: system-installation, kernel, surface

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my Surface Laptop 4 (AMD), but after preparing the USB bootable drive with Ubuntu, it freezes while trying to "try" Ubuntu. I met the same behavior when trying to install Linux Mint also.

Researching for solutions, I read many mentions of the need to install or recompile the kernel. I have very limited knowledge about Linux, so "install kernel" does not make any sense to me; I'm coming from a Windows environment and I don't know how to do that.

My request is simple: is there any Ubuntu version that has the geek stuff needed for this hardware installed and all I have to do is create a bootable USB and try Ubuntu?  I need a beginner-friendly answer.

Comment: Assuming the hardware meets the min spec of what ever version of Ubuntu you are trying to install they all work. Did you follow a tutorial to do the making of the USB device and install? The link to the official guide. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Comment: What are the hardware specs and what version of Ubuntu are you trying to use?